# Extract alias from Freebase dump

Tags: alias, freebase

I have downloaded the Freebase dump from https://developers.google.com/freebase/data?hl=en, but I am confused about the relation of the file.

I know the format of the dump is `<subject>  <predicate>  <object> .`. If I want to extract the alias subset of Freebase, like http://www.freebase.com/common/topic/alias?instances&lang=en, how can I do for this?
I have tried to filter the lines that contains the mid or '/common/topic/alias', but the result is not what I want.

Is there any library to parse Freebase? Thanks!

**Follow up:**

I have two more questions.

1. Is there a list that shows all the namespace in freebase? (e.g. `type.object.name` is the name of object)
2. How can extract all the 'type of (IS A)' relations? (e.g. C++ IS A programming language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Freebase data dump is RDF, so any RDF parsing library should work, but `zgrep` would be a lot quicker.  One little twist is that the predicate for the Freebase property `/common/topic/alias` is `<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/common.topic.alias>` with the slashes converted to periods/dots.

To filter just the English aliases, you can use a command like:

```
$ zgrep -E "common.topic.alias>.*@en\t\.$" freebase-rdf-2015-04-19-00-00.gz
```

Which will give you output looking like:

```
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.0100c5g>  <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/common.topic.alias> "Pulska yo"@en  .
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.0101107q> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/common.topic.alias> "Unforgiven 2002"@en    .
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.01016v4g> <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/common.topic.alias> "Ain't Nuthin' But A \"G\" Thang, Rene"@en  .
...
```

If you want aliases in all languages, you can just use:

```
$ zgrep -E "common.topic.alias>" freebase-rdf-2015-04-19-00-00.gz
```

Comment: You are right!! The slashes are all converted to dots. But the parameter '-E' doesn't work here, I used '-P' instead. Thank you!

Comment: I have two new questions, could you give me some tips?

Comment: If you post your new questions, I'm sure someone will help.